# Merge 2 similar tables in Access, Total 1 Column and keep all unmatched

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table
tblCountResults

```
**Columns**
Activity
MinOfName
CountOfActivity
```

Table
tblCountResultsSQL

```
**Columns**
Activity
MinOfName
CountOfActivity
```

What i need is to merge those 2 tables into one. I need the CountofActivity from both tables to be added together IF the Activity matches. I need the Activity and MinOfName to be kept whether there is a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this, but I'm not sure how MinofName is going to be treated if there's multiple of them for the same activity...

```
Select coalesce(A.activity, B.Activity) as Activity, 
 coalesce(A.MinofName, B.MinofName) as MinOfName, 
 coalesce(A.countofActivity,0) + coalesce(b.CountofActivity) as SumofcountofActivty
FROM tblCountResults A Full outer Join tblCountResultsSQL B 
  ON A.Activity = B.Activity
```

Comment: From what i am reading there is no full outer join in access. is that true?

Comment: no.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx

Comment: But the note says " NOTE   You cannot define a full outer join in an Access database."

Comment: you seem to be correct...  http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3516561/Implementing-the-Equivalent-of-a-FULL-OUTER-JOIN-in-Microsoft-Access.htm.  However it can be simulated with two left joins and a union

Answer (score 0):

```
select isnull(t1.activity, t2.activity) as activity,
isnull(t1.MinOfName, t2.MinOfName) as MinOfName,
isnull(t1.CountOfActivity, 0) + isnull(t2.CountOfActivity, 0) as count
from tblCountResults t1
full outer join tblCountResultsSQL t2 on t2.activity = t2.activity
```

Comment: From what i am reading there is no full outer join in access. is that true?